How to label bar plots with error bars in Matplotlib/Seaborn?
I have seen numerous posts trying to do one or the other (ie. add error bars or add bar labels), but I'm wondering, how can I do it for both?
Right now, I'm doing something like:
sns.barplot(ax=axes[0],
        data=predictions_to_plot_df, x='variable', y='value', hue=hue_column
    )

for container in axes[0].containers:
  axes[0].bar_label(container, padding=-40)

However, the padding on bar_label does not correspond well if I try and play around with ylim, for example. I would ideally like to display both height value and error bars on the same plot, without one overlapping with another. In my mind, I would somehow be able to place the bar label always beneath the error bar or always at the bottom of the ylim range.
Is this possible?


You'll need to label the bars manually:
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bp = sns.barplot(penguins, x="island", y="body_mass_g", hue="sex", ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(2000)

# labels at bottom of ylim range
for c in bp.containers:
    for i, r in enumerate(c):
        ax.text(r.get_center()[0], ax.get_ylim()[0], f"{c.datavalues[i]:.0f}", va='bottom', ha='center',c='white')

# labels beneath errorbars
l = 0
for c in bp.containers:
    for d in c.datavalues.tolist():
        ax.text(bp.lines[l].get_xdata()[0], bp.lines[l].get_ydata()[0], f"{d:.0f}", va='top', ha='center',c='white')
        l += 1


If you want to offset the text a bit from the spine or the error bar's end, you can use annotate instead of text, which allows to use a pad in placing the text:
pad = 5  # points

# labels at bottom of ylim range
for c in bp.containers:
    for i, r in enumerate(c):
        ax.annotate(f"{c.datavalues[i]:.0f}", (r.get_center()[0], ax.get_ylim()[0]), (0, pad), textcoords='offset points', va='bottom', ha='center', c='white')

# labels beneath errorbars
l = 0
for c in bp.containers:
    for d in c.datavalues.tolist():
        ax.annotate(f"{d:.0f}", bp.lines[l].get_xydata()[0], (0, -pad),  textcoords='offset points', va='top', ha='center', c='white')
        l += 1


